# How to get nested JSON export using django-import-export?

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin, django-import-export

I'm using django-import-export and I want to do exports to JSON in which relations are nested. So let's say I use [the example from the docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#getting-started) (Book/Author/Category) and I want to do an export of all books, including it's authors and categories. I would expect the export to include the authors and categories as objects so that it looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy",
        "Author": {"name": "Douglas Adams"}
        "categories": [{"name": "Science fiction"}, {"name": "classics"}]
        "imported": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Don Quixote",
        "Author": {"name": "Miguel de Cervantes"},
        "categories": [{"name": "Idiots"}]
        "imported": true
    }
]
```

I'm looking through the documentation but I can't find how I could achieve that. How can I achieve that?

### Edit

The reason I'm trying to do this is that we have some models containing specific settings which we test in Acceptance. Once they are good to go I want to be able to do an export from acceptance, and then import that into production. Likewise, I also want to be able to export from production and import in acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a simple way of doing this in django-import-export but it is possible to generate nested data structures using [`dehydrate()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#advanced-data-manipulation-on-export) methods.

For example, in the example application one can produce a nested Author field as follows:

```py
class BookResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Book

    def dehydrate_author(self, book):
        author = getattr(book, "author", None)
        if author:
            return {"name": author.name}
        return dict()
```

This will result in a data structure like:

```json
[{"id": 101, "name": "Fly Fishing", "author": {"name": "J. R. Hartley"}}]
```

Comment: I guess this part will only really enable the export? Any ideas about importing?

Comment: yes you can import JSON data - refer to [tablib](https://github.com/jazzband/tablib) - (used as the data format in django-import-export)